# Giving focus to GNOME docked window

Tags: gtk, focus, window, gnome, dock

I've got a GTK/GDK docked window that I need to give keyboard focus to, so accelerator keys (shortcuts) work.  Does anybody know if GNOME even allows a docked window to have keyboard focus, and if so, how can I enable it?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Could you provide some source code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I really can't.  However, the code is fairly simple, it's just making a GDK window docked.  This in turn makes the window unable to recieve (maintain?) keyboard focus.  I mainly want this so shortcuts like Ctrl-J are picked up.  I also put a GTK text input box in the window for testing, and I'm unable type anything into it, so there is simply no keyboard focus whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried gtk_widget_grab_focus (), and set GTK_CAN_FOCUS flag on dock widget?

Comment: thanks for the response.  yes, i have. unfortunately it doesn't seem to have any affect.